# How can I improve the LAG function?

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I have the following table:

| time | comsales | indsales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20.96 | 127.3 |
| 2 | 21.4 | 130 |
| 3 | 21.96 | 132.7 |
| 4 | 21.52 | 129.4 |
| 5 | 22.39 | 135 |
| 6 | 22.76 | 137.1 |
| 7 | 23.48 | 141.2 |
| 8 | 23.66 | 142.8 |
| 9 | 24.1 | 145.5 |
| 10 | 24.01 | 145.3 |
| 11 | 24.54 | 148.3 |
| 12 | 24.3 | 146.4 |
| 13 | 25 | 150.2 |
| 14 | 25.64 | 153.1 |
| 15 | 26.36 | 157.3 |
| 16 | 26.98 | 160.7 |
| 17 | 27.52 | 164.2 |
| 18 | 27.78 | 165.6 |
| 19 | 28.24 | 168.7 |
| 20 | 28.78 | 171.7 |

I am trying to implement a LAG function in python with the following code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

dataset = pd.read_csv('Data/blaisdellcomp.csv', index_col=0)
y = dataset['comsales']
x = dataset['indsales']

X = sm.add_constant(x)
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(model.summary())

residuals = model.resid
residuals = residuals.reset_index(drop=True)

lagged_residuals = residuals.rolling(1).sum()
lagged_residuals.drop(lagged_residuals.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
lagged_residuals.loc[-1] = lagged_residuals[0]  # adding a row
lagged_residuals.index = lagged_residuals.index + 1  # shifting index
lagged_residuals.sort_index(inplace=True)
lagged_residuals = lagged_residuals.reset_index(drop=True)
```

To be able to make a lag in the residuals I use a lot of code to implement the lag. Is there a better way to implement the lag on the residuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the [Pandas `shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) method:

`lagged_residuals = residuals.shift(1)`